# Bad result with encoding when Selecting arabic data from SQLite & android

Tags: android, sqlite, text, encoding, arabic

I have a problem with SQLite and android,
I`m trying to select arabic data from the db, the db filled by the data outside android and i push it to android emulator..
the english text appears normaly but the arabic text appear in wrong way

the text appears like this img
[image]

so help me plz

Comment: **Important thing**: Are you using any Arabic font to show it perfectly?

Comment: What output do you get from `SELECT HEX(SomeColumnWithArabicText)`?

Comment: @ImranRana, yes i am using library for arabic and it work perfect with static text .. but when i select from db.. the text appear as it in the img.

Comment: @dan04 emm i dont know where i can execute ur code ?!
i used this ..
Cursor c = wDB.query("tbCategory", null, null, null, null, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

I checked with Arabic database with random text created via code:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("dictionary", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LIST(wlist varchar);");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('صبالخير');"); 
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('صبا لخير');");
```

Then I used following query with cursor to dynamically select text from database:

```
String q = "SELECT * FROM LIST";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null);
if(c.getCount() == 0)
  {
    setSuggestions(list, true, true);
  }
else{
  int i=0;
  c.moveToFirst();
     do {
         String cm = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("wlist")); 
                      list.add(cm);
                      i++;
        } while (c.moveToNext() && i<30);
```

The result is as follows:

[image]
Arabic text is shown. So, check your existing database with a SQLite Database Browser if Arabic data is in correct form there.