# Arabic String getting from sqlite in android ,not show properly?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, arabic

i am working on an Islamic app.
i am getting an Arabic string from Sq-lite DataBase but when i try to show this string ,not show properly.
i have also set encoding UTF-8 of java page.
but when i use this string directly it shows in proper style.
i am also using a typeface.but not solve my problem
any body can help?
tell me some solution to solve this.
my code is here..

```
String arabic ="ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ";
```

when i use this it works.
but when i use string from sqlite db it not show proper.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Variables.....
TextView arabicTV,urduTV;
TableLayout tablelayout;
TableRow tableRow;
Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tablelayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
    Typeface arabicFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Al Qalam Quran Publisher.ttf");

        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        Cursor c =db.getAllAyyat();
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String value = c.getString(0);
                System.out.println(value);
                tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new      TableRow.LayoutParams(450, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(lp);
                lp.setMargins(4, 3, 6, 8);
                arabicTV = new TextView(this);
                arabicTV.setLayoutParams(lp);
                arabicTV.setText(value);
                arabicTV.setTypeface(arabicFont);
                arabicTV.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                arabicTV.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                arabicTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                arabicTV.setTextSize(40);
                tableRow.addView(arabicTV);
                tablelayout.addView(tableRow);
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: @prince now see my code i update this

Comment: What is there in Log for :  System.out.println(value);

Comment: ..ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ this is the log for this for one value

Comment: So is it not correct which you want ?

Comment: check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518409/bad-result-with-encoding-when-selecting-arabic-data-from-sqlite-andriod

Comment: maybe you got some help.

Answer (score 1):

it got nothing to do with UTF-8 or type of fonts,,, I have in my app 7 deferent languages and android system can show them all clearly.

let the cursor inquire the data base then use c.getString(0); here an example : [Retrieving single data from SQLite and display in TextView (Android Development)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876560/retrieving-single-data-from-sqlite-and-display-in-textview-android-development)

if it still didn't work with you,,, I'm more than glad to help as possible,,, jouid33@gmail.com